# RestAssured external file logging

Tags: java, rest, logging, rest-assured

Using requestSpecBuilder in rest-assured , i am getting the logs two times in my log file. How to disable this?

```
 @BeforeClass
    public void initSpec() {




        spec = new RequestSpecBuilder().setContentType(ContentType.JSON).setBaseUri(Utils.getHostName()).setAccept(ContentType.JSON)
                .setContentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .build();
    }
```

My log file looks like this: -

```
02:08:26.547 [main] INFO  com.agileapps.settings.controller.api.userpassword.U_UserPasswordControllerTest - Start of changePassword_CurrentNewPasswordSame
02:08:26.547 [main] INFO  com.agileapps.settings.controller.api.userpassword.U_UserPasswordControllerTest - Start of changePassword_CurrentNewPasswordSame
02:08:26.553 [main] INFO  com.agileapps.settings.controller.api.userpassword.U_UserPasswordControllerTest - URL: https://settings/user-password
02:08:26.553 [main] INFO  com.agileapps.settings.controller.api.userpassword.U_UserPasswordControllerTest - URL: https://settings/user-password
02:08:27.641 [main] INFO  com.agileapps.settings.controller.api.userpassword.U_UserPasswordControllerTest - End of changePassword_CurrentNewPasswordSame
02:08:27.641 [main] INFO  com.agileapps.settings.controller.api.userpassword.U_UserPasswordControllerTest - End of changePassword_CurrentNewPasswordSame
02:08:27.643 [main] INFO  com.agileapps.settings.controller.api.userpassword.U_UserPasswordControllerTest - Start of changePassword_CurrentPasswordNull
02:08:27.643 [main] INFO  com.agileapps.settings.controller.api.userpassword.U_UserPasswordControllerTest - Start of changePassword_CurrentPasswordNull
02:08:27.644 [main] INFO  com.agileapps.settings.controller.api.userpassword.U_UserPasswordControllerTest - URL: https://settings/user-password
02:08:27.644 [main] INFO  com.agileapps.settings.controller.api.userpassword.U_UserPasswordControllerTest - URL: https://settings/user-password
```

log4j.xml file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
       <Properties>
        <Property name="basePath">./logs</Property>
      </Properties>

  <Appenders>
      <RollingFile name="File" fileName="${basePath}/Settings.log" filePattern="${basePath}/Re-EngineeringLogs-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
     <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
      <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250000000" />
          </RollingFile>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.agileapps.settings.test.employee.PostObject" level="trace">
       <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
       </Logger>
    <Root level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

But i am getting this error due to addition of method initSpec() as shown above.

Comment: These are not rest-assured logs

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution fixed by changing my log4j.xml file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="basePath">./logs</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="AgileAppsFileAppender"
            fileName="${basePath}/settings.log"
            filePattern="${basePath}/settings-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250000000" />
        </RollingFile>
        <Console name="AgileAppsConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.agileapps.settings" level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="AgileAppsFileAppender" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="warn">
            <AppenderRef ref="AgileAppsConsoleAppender" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```